# How do I create a reminder for an oven warmer?

Tags: kitchen

I have a gas powered warmer below my oven. You only see the switch for it when you open the warmer and it located below the oven near the floor, so it is very innocuous. Whenever I use it I forget about it and inevitably there is some food that gets left in there and "warmed" for 2 or 3 days (or more) before I notice somehow and turn the thing off. I only use it when I am entertaining, so the environment it gets used in is distracting to begin with.

I need some easy way to remind myself to turn off the warmer after the party is over.

Answer (score 2):

For so many aspects of life that require the monitoring of time, one may find that the personal communications devices that are so commonplace will certainly fit the bill. Timers and alarm apps are integrated into the device operating system; many such enhanced apps are available from respective repositories.

Short version: set a timer or alarm on one's phone.

Answer (score 2):

Just before you turn on the warmer, tape an oven mitt to the front of the drawer.
Don't remove it until you have turned off the warmer.

[image]

(You could use a fridge magnet instead, but you want something that's as obvious as possible.)

---

Or, more conveniently, if it's possible to do with your oven, tie a piece of red cloth or ribbon to the inside of the warmer.

Whenever you use it, to avoid burning the material you'll have to move it so that it hangs outside the drawer.